# Regexp replacement string, what am I doing wrong?

Tags: regex, go

I am building a simple markdown to html parser and I cannot get my regular expression replacement to work. What am I doing wrong?

I have tried multiple different variations and googling but still can't get it to work properly.

Markdown:

```
# Hello World!
```

Code:

```
content, readErr := ioutil.ReadFile(markdownFile)
contentString := string(content)

h1 := regexp.MustCompile(`^#(.*)`)
contentHTML := h1.ReplaceAllStrings(contentString, `<h1>$1</h1>`)

fmt.Println(contentHTML)
```

Expected Output:

```
<h1>Hello World!</h1>
```

Actual Output:

```
</h1>Hello World!
```

I'm sure its a simple mistake but I am at a lose for how I am getting the output that I am.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I fix the `ReplaceAllString` method, it works just fine:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "regexp"
)

func main() {
    contentString := "# Hello World!"

    h1 := regexp.MustCompile(`^#(.*)`)
    contentHTML := h1.ReplaceAllString(contentString, `<h1>$1</h1>`)
    fmt.Println(contentHTML)
}
```

Prints:

```
<h1> Hello World!</h1>
```

[See it on the playground](https://play.golang.org/p/8cSJoxJ05-z)

Notes:

- Your regexp captures the whitespace following the `#`, which you probably don't really want. Consider changing it to something like `^#\s+(.*)`.
- Generally, converting from one format to another using regexps is rather error-prone and may result in very complicated code. For a simple exercise it's fine, but don't do this in production :)